# QMenu set icon and text visible for title and items

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am designing the style of my app.
I didn't managed to find how to set the icon and the text visible for QMenu's title and items

For now i my QMenu show the icon and not the title. 
When I press it the title is visible (Wtf??)
Icon of items are never visible.

What I have

[image: press]
[image: unpress]

What I Would Like

[image: i want that]

I am using PyQt4

Example of my code

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import time
import os


class Ariadne_main_window (QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
        myIcon = QtGui.QIcon("import_bdd.png")
        import_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu(myIcon, "&Import")

        add_visit_action = QtGui.QAction('&Add visit ...', self)
        add_visit_action.triggered.connect(self.add_visits)
        add_visit_action.setToolTip("Add Spectrum in the database")
        myIcon2 = QtGui.QIcon("galaxie_plus.png")
        add_visit_action.setIcon(myIcon2)
        import_menu.addAction(add_visit_action)

        QtGui.QToolTip.setFont(QtGui.QFont('SansSerif', 10))
        QtGui.QApplication.setStyle(QtGui.QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))

        self.show()

    def add_visits(self):
        print("Add visit clicked")


def main_function():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet("""QToolTip {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    padding: 2px;
    color:black;
}
QToolBar{
    icon-size:25px;
}
QMenu::indicator {
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
}
QMenu::item{
    padding: 2px 32px 2px 20px;
    icon-size:15px;
}""")
    main_window_object = Ariadne_main_window()
    app.exec_()
    time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main_function()
```

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it would be great to show an image of what you want.